# nested element firing parent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have a `jsp` that generates the following html structure:

```
<ul class="folders" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_727">
    <li class="folder" style="cursor: pointer;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_726">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Prueba 1 
        <ul class="files" style="display: block;">
            <li class="file"> <a href="/documents/10184/10675/welcome_tools" target="_blank" class="link"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> welcome_tools </a> </li>
            <li class="file"> <a href="/documents/10184/10675/welcome_learn" target="_blank" class="link"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> welcome_learn </a> </li>
            <li class="file"> <a href="/documents/10184/10675/welcome_cube" target="_blank" class="link"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> welcome_cube </a> </li>
            <li class="file"> <a href="/documents/10184/10675/welcome_community" target="_blank" class="link"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> welcome_community </a> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="folders" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_725" style="display: block;">
            <li class="folder" style="cursor: pointer;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_724">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Sub 1 
                <ul class="files" style="display: block;">
                    <li class="file"> <a href="/documents/10184/10707/helpful_links_for_using_liferay_portal" target="_blank" class="link"> <i class="fa fa-file"></i> helpful_links_for_using_liferay_portal </a> </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="folders" style="display: block;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_798">
                    <li class="folder" style="cursor: pointer;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1410259364795_797">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Sub Sub 1 
                        <ul class="folders" style="display: block;"> </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And  i have the following javascript

```
$("li.folder")
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", function(){

        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("ul.files,ul.folders").toggle(200);

        return false;
});
```

For a tree-like functionality.

**The problem is** whenever i click an `a` it fires the `li.folder` event. How can i make it so that the link behaves as a link.

Codepen link:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hokgt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just exclude the anchor

```
$("li.folder")
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", function(e){

        if ( ! $(e.target).is('a') ) {

            $(this).find("ul.files,ul.folders").toggle(200);

        }

        return false;
});
```

or go the other way, and stop the propagation

```
$("li.folder a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Your first suggestion didn´t work for me, but the second one did!